# Does Gaeuko, Guardian of the Night in Basque mythology, connect with the notion of "upperness" or "superiority" denoted by the Basque word "goiko"?

Tags: basque

In Basque mythology, [Gaueko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaueko) is the spirit or guardian of the night. He does not allow certain types of work to be done outside at nighttime, and he punishes those who boast that they are not afraid of the dark. He sometimes makes his presence felt as a gust of wind, or takes the form of a [black dog](https://exemplore.com/advanced-ancients/mythologicaldogsparti) or a bull. His name literally means "of the night" and appears in phrases such as "gaueko hontza" (night owl) and "gaueko hasperenak" (night sighs).

Does Gaeuko connect with the notion of "upperness" or "superiority" denoted by the Basque word "goiko"?